# Produce a "type" attribute in the "script" tag when using Scripts.Render in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

Is it possible to configure Scripts.Render in ASP.NET MVC 4 to produce a "type" attribute in the "script" tag?

If so, how?

Thanks in advance,

Ryan

Comment: There is nothing native in ASP.NET MVC 4 that is called `Scripts.Render`.

Comment: @SebNilsson This is `web optimization framework` package, that included in MVC 4 by default.

Comment: @webdeveloper it's actually a separate package `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`.

Comment: @jrummell Thanks, I knew it ;) And this package http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/1.0.0 included, not part of MVC 4 by default. That's my words and OP asking about how to override rendering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 1.1-alpha1 update has support doing your own tag formatting with the Scripts/Styles helpers.

There's a new DefaultTagFormat property which is by default set to:

```
"<script src="{0}"></script>"
```

There's also a RenderFormat method which takes in the tag format as well. You should be able to add the type attribute via either of these two mechanicsms.