# Asp.Net MVC 4 bundle don't provide <script> section attributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, asp.net-optimization

My actual question is:

How can I create `<script>` section with attributes using Asp.Net Mvc bundle optimization?

I need to be able to get something like this in my result html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjavascript.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

The reason is that my "myjavascript.js" contains unicode characters and in browser i've got square symbols instead of my original text.

Can I do that with Asp.Net bundle optimization classes?

"Fast googling" says that I can't.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that you cannot do that. But you could save the javascript file as UTF-8 with BOM and have your site also use UTF-8:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Now the unicode characters stored in your javascript file will display properly.

Comment: Ok, I've got it, your solution works well in my case. Thanks a lot!
But it seems strange that I can't apply my attributes to <script> tag when using asp.net script optimization feature.

Comment: This answer is not correct. You _can_ do that using Scripts.RenderFormat as Hao Kung reported. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232566/how-to-set-charset-to-js-file-in-mvc-scriptbundle

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the RenderFormat method to customize how the Scripts helper renders tags:

[Produce a "type" attribute in the "script" tag when using Scripts.Render in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051301/produce-a-type-attribute-in-the-script-tag-when-using-scripts-render-in-asp)