# How to set charset to .js file in MVC ScriptBundle?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, character-encoding, bundle

I have script.js file that contains several string in cyrillic. When i attempt to load this with standart link like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Script/Script.js"></script>
```

cyrillic letters become rectangulars/badCharsetCaracters.

This  solves the broblem:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Script/Script.js" charset="windows-1251"></script>`

How can I set charset with ASP.NET MVC 4 Bundles? Code like this:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include(
                     "~/Content/Script/Script.js"));
```

Comment: Ideally you should be saving and serving your files only in UTF-8 rather than loading a `windows-1251`-encoded file into other documents. The web is quickly embracing UTF-8, for example JSON absolutely requires UTF-8 encoding, for example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [Scripts.RenderFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.scripts.renderformat.aspx) to specify your custom script tag rendering format:

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat(
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\" charset=\"windows-1251\"></script>", 
    "~/bundles/scripts")
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your script file's encoding to your website's encoding.

For example, if your site is encoded in UTF-8, then:

1. Open your script file in the windows' notepad
2. Click File > Save as
3. Change encoding to UTF-8 (list of encodings is in front od the "Save" button)