# How do I add type="text/javascript" to a script tag when using System.Web.Optimization

Tags: c#, asp.net, xhtml, bundling-and-minification, system.web.optimization

I have the following

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/common").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js",
                  "~/Scripts/common.js"));
```

Which generates

```
<script src="/bundles/scripts/common?v=9O0Yi3fV_GWpGyJQ_QYURiOYy6SEmxUQtkUVN4GXo2U1"></script>
```

When rendered with

```
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderJs" runat="server">                
            <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts/common") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Which is not valid HTML as its missing type="text/javascript".  How do I make the BundleCollection output this element in the script tag?

Comment: Do you mean type="text/javascript"? If so, and you're using HTML5, the type attribute isn't needed.

Comment: Hi, I did mean javascript (post edited).  Its not HTML5 though. Thanks.

Comment: Refer  “Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.” Error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467404/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Produce a "type" attribute in the "script" tag when using Scripts.Render in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051301/produce-a-type-attribute-in-the-script-tag-when-using-scripts-render-in-asp)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way is to change how you render your scripts:

From:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts/common")
```

To:

```
<script src="@BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/scripts/common")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or depending on how you are implementing bundling, you may need:

```
<script src="@Microsoft.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/scripts/common")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or for web forms:

```
<script src="<%= Microsoft.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/scripts/common")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Although if there is a way to do it using @Script.Render I'd like to see it.

**UPDATE:** in response to your comments, as specified in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14882255/1810243), in the pre-release version of `System.Web.Optimization`, there is an option called `RenderFormat` that will let you do this as well... but I think the stuff above is easier to read for this particular case.

Comment: Thanks, spotted a post with this method in but I thought it was probably not the most effective way.  Maybe this is the way to go for now.

Comment: @jondow What makes it not effective?

Comment: What is mean is that I expected there to be a built in method such as a overload on the Scripts.Render method or a property that could be set on the ScriptBundle object.

Comment: It case enable bundling and minification even on debug. How possible disable it on debug?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer marked is not correct for `type="text/css"`, it is correct for JavaScript (maybe the question title is misleading?). For CSS files you should use

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/common")
```

and **not** `@Scripts.Render(...)`. The reason is that minification is done, and only `@Styles.Render(...)` knows about Cascading Stylesheet syntax, `@Scripts.Render(...)` is specialized for JavaScript minification.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it like that

```
>      bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
>                             "~/Scripts/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"));
```

i think you need to replace ~/bundles/scripts/common with ~/bundles/jquery

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it like that

```
bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
        "~/Scripts/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    )
);
```

I think you need to replace `~/bundles/scripts/common` with `~/bundles/jquery`