# Script Rendering in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Following is from cshtml in a ASP.Net MVC 4 View

I have a meta tag

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

I have a Render script

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/UpdateHeader.js")
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But it is rendering as:

```
<script src="/Scripts/UpdateHeader.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The type is missing:

```
type="text/javascript"
```

What is the best way to include type along with `@Scripts.Render` ?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 the type attribute is not necessary.

But if you still need it (if perhaps you are targeting older browsers), then this answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15663014/606602