# Is there an easy way to render absolute URLs with Microsoft Web Optimization framework / script bundling?

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification, scriptbundle

I'm trying to render a JavaScript bundle using Microsoft's Web Optimization framework, like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/assets/bundle.js")
```

And building a small bundle, like this:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/assets/bundle.js")
        .Include(
            "~/scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js",
            "~/scripts/somescript.js"
        ));

    ...
}
```

But when optimizations are on, it only renders a relative URL, like this:

```
<script src="/assets/bundle.js?v=mGDOiNaiTrSfcNq41OoA7A_BcN8PrXuMbfl-TE84HVY1"></script>
```

**How can I have script bundling render an absolute URL instead?**  I couldn't find a way to do this looking through the docs on MSDN.  This is what I would ultimately like:

```
<script src="http://my.site.com/assets/bundle.js?v=mGDOiNaiTrSfcNq41OoA7A_BcN8PrXuMbfl-TE84HVY1"></script>
```

Is this in the framework, or do I have to roll a helper method with `Script.Url`?

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15663014/1810243). Though IDK if there may be a better way to do in newer version of bundling. What is your end-goal in doing this?

Comment: That still resolves to a relative URL unfortunately.  The relative paths generally work fine for the browser, but don't work well for UI controls (say in iOS) where you don't provide a baseURL.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One easy way is with [Scripts.RenderFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.scripts.renderformat(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='http://my.site.com{0}'></script>","~/assets/bundle.js")
```

A way to get URL from request. Couldn't seem to use multiple parameters with the RenderFormat, so that's why it looks a little ugly:

```
 @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='//" + @Request.Url.Host + "/{0}'></script>", "~/assets/bundle.js")
```

or better yet, centralize a function to get the correct path (using a fictional function):

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script src='" + @Tools.GetRootURL() + "{0}'></script>", "~/assets/bundle.js")
```

Also, you don't need the `.js` on the bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/assets/bundle")
```

Comment: Thanks for this; I agree this would work, although then I'd have to config drive a root URL per environment when I'd really rather it go off of the host / virtual app path.  If it's truly absent from the framework, then I'd try to infer it from the request.

Comment: @BrandonLinton added way to determine URL from request.