# Conditionally Render MVC bundles in a Angular bootstrapped MVC app

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have bootstrapped Angular with a ASP.NET MVC app. How do I conditionally load the MVC bundles based on what Angular view is getting rendered.

Index.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="maypp">
<body>

    <div class="container">

        @*HEADER*@
        <div header></div>


        <div ui-view></div>

        @*FOOTER*@
        <div footer></div>

    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bundle1")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bundle2")

</body>
</html>
```

I need to load bundle1 for Angular view 1 only. Other views need to include both bundle1 and bundle2. I am using AngularJS, not Angular 2. Any response is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load external scripts dynamically in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/how-to-load-external-scripts-dynamically-in-angular)

Comment: See also [Is there an easy way to render absolute URLs with Microsoft Web Optimization framework / script bundling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731577/is-there-an-easy-way-to-render-absolute-urls-with-microsoft-web-optimization-fra).

Comment: @CodeCaster That response is for Angular 2. I am using AngularJS in my app.

Comment: You can apply the same principles explained there.

Comment: I am neither using WebPack nor the System.JS. Not sure how that answer would translate to a AngularJS solution.

Comment: Look Dude, in the end it comes down to appending a `<script>` tag to your DOM pointing to a JS file. Sure, how you do that might differ from AngularJS to Angular2, but the principle remains. Instead of trying to find the differences, look at the commonalities.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Angular in general, but wouln't using two different `_Layout.cshtml` files with their respective bundles solve it for you? Then you'd import them at the beginning of each View.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in the bottom of your cshtml view. However, you might want replace random number checker with your business logic :)

**Option 1:**

```
@section Scripts {

    @if (new Random().Next(10) > 5)
    {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/x")
    }
    else
    {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/y")
    }

}
```

**Option 2:**

Bundle 1:

```
function startBundleOne(){
   //bundle logic
}
```

Bundle 2:

```
function startBundleTwo(){
   //bundle logic
}
```

AngularJS view:

```
if (something){
    startBundleOne();
} else {
    startBundleTwo();
}
```

**Option 3:**

```
var scriptPath;
    if (something){
        scriptPath = "pathA";
    } else {
        scriptPath = "pathB";
    }
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src',scriptPath);
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: The business logic for the if condition is where I am stuck. I need to check that the view rendered by Angular is ViewA or not before loading the scripts. But the issue is that Angular is a client side rendering engine and the Index.cshtml is not reloaded when Angular loads a new view.

Comment: Ok that's trickier. In that case you could load both budles, wrap your bundles each in a different global function without executing them, and call that global function from an angular script.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how that can be accomplished? (with a sample)

Comment: I added option 2 and option 3, both of these should work

Answer (score 0):

You are using Angular UI Router, it will be easy that way. Create two separate states such as for bundle 1, app1 and for bundle 2, app2 as shown below:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app1', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/app1',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
});
$stateProvider
  .state('app2', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/app2',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
})
```

After this use [oclazyload](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) library to load the bundles for different states as shown below:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app1', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/app1',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    resolve: {
      plugins: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
          '~/bundles/bundle1.js'
        ]);
      }]
    }

});
$stateProvider
  .state('app2', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/app2',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    resolve: {
      plugins: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
          '~/bundles/bundle2.js'
        ]);
      }]
    }
})
```

Now you have two different states running with two different bundles. I have implemented this in one of my projects and it is working flawlessly.

Update:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('app1', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/app1',
        template: '<div ui-view></div>',
        resolve: {
          plugins: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
              '~/bundles/bundle1.js'
            ]);
          }]
        }

      })
      .state('app2', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/app2',
        template: '<div ui-view></div>',
        resolve: {
          plugins: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
              '~/bundles/bundle2.js'
            ]);
          }]
        }
      })
  }])
```

Comment: I am using MVC bundling, so I don't think I can load `          ~/bundles/bundle2.js`

Comment: Also, how does index.cshtml get updated with this implementation? Does it need 2 ng-app attributes?

Comment: No only one ng-app is required and inside the application config you need to mention these two states.

Comment: See the update and mark as answer if you are satisfied with the information that i have given.