# How to output type=javascript from Scripts.Render using bundles

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

In My Master page I have the following lines :

```
<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/SiteJS") %>
```

It correctly outputs the bundles as :

```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Main.js"></script>
```

But I want it like this with `type="text/javascript"`

```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What needs to be done for this ?

This post [How do I add type="text/javascript" to a script tag when using System.Web.Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662096/how-do-i-add-type-text-javascript-to-a-script-tag-when-using-system-web-optimi)
focuses on a single javascript file but I have many files in that bundle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add type="text/javascript" to a script tag when using System.Web.Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662096/how-do-i-add-type-text-javascript-to-a-script-tag-when-using-system-web-optimi)

Comment: @NaveenGogineni that post is using optimization as well. I am just using bundling. so that solution does not work for me..

Comment: How about this `<script src="@BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/scripts/common")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @NaveenGogineni it outputs 3 scripts together. I want to output the bundle script one by one. see my expected output